# 12.04 upgrade libav from 53 to 54

Tags: 12.04, apt, libav

I am using the latest release of blender 2.66 on 12.04 from the command line. It is looking for libavformat.so.54 but I only seem to have libavformat.so.53 installed, and cant find a way to upgrade to the 54 release.  Trying `apt-get upgrade` doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

6 months later... my latest upgrade of blender (2.69) which I keep updated through software-sources of the gui Update Manager from:
 http://ppa.launchpad.net/irie/blender/ubuntu
now includes the libavformat.so.55 library in the blender/ffmpeg/2.0/ directory along with latest versions of other ffmpeg tools.  likewise libavformat.so.54 is included in the blender/ffmpeg/1.2/ directory, so they are kept updated by the hard work of IRIE Shinsuke.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 repository contains [blender (2.62-1)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/blender) and [libavformat53](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libavformat53) which provides libavformat.so.53 file.

So you should either install blender from repository or build yourself not only latest version of blender but some of it's dependencies also.

Using repository is best way until you need some functions of latest release.

Comment: Hi apmouse, I need some of the latest functionality. I downloaded the latest blender using:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender

I know I might be chasing after dependencies, but is there any way to download 54 on its own?

Comment: plucke, i don't see this package in popular repositories. But you can download sources from [home page](http://libav.org/download.html#release_9)